# Maven rename included file

Tags: maven, jar, maven-3, maven-plugin

When building a `jar` I want to include a file, rename it and put it inside of the `jar` but `Maven` puts the renamed file in the target folder instead of putting inside of the `jar`. How can I rename a file that I want to be included inside of the `jar`?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>filter-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>../rest-api/src/main/resources/xcs-${xcs.rest.api.version}.yaml</include><!-- File I want to rename -->
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-and-rename-file</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>rename</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceFile>../rest-api/src/main/resources/xcs-${xcs.rest.api.version}.yaml</sourceFile>
                        <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/xcs.yaml</destinationFile><!-- Desired name -->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Firstly, you yourself putting the file in target directory as ${project.build.directory} refers to target directory. You can use ${project.build.outputDirectory} ,which will place the file under target/classes folder.  If it is still not placing the renamed file in jar, please take a look at the plugin configuration you are using to build the jar.

Comment: @MadhavKumarJha It worked! Any idea why it moves the file which I want to rename instead of copying it?

Comment: The question I'm thinking of is: Why do you need to rename it all cause the result should always be `xcs.yaml`? So why not putting that into the project already instead of renaming it? And another interesting thing: Why do you use a resource from a different module (based on `../rest-api/..`)?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using a file from different module because I want to reuse Swagger configuration from this file. I refer to this file in my second Swagger configuration, but because I can't use Maven variables in Swagger configs I'm trying to remove version from the file by renaming it. I don't want to hardcode file name and then replace file references each time the version changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to copy and rename the file with the wrong goal and execution id.
Try this:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-rename</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
...
```